# Using CURL to download file and view headers and status code

Tags: bash, curl

I'm writing a Bash script to download image files from [Snapito](http://snapito.com)'s web page snapshot API.  The API can return a variety of responses indicated by different HTTP response codes and/or some custom headers.  My script is intended to be run as an automated Cron job that pulls URLs from a MySQL database and saves the screenshots to local disk.

I am using `curl`.  I'd like to do these 3 things using a single CURL command:

1. Extract the HTTP response code
2. Extract the headers
3. Save the file locally (if the request was successful)

I could do this using multiple `curl` requests, but I want to minimize the number of times I hit Snapito's servers.  Any `curl` experts out there?

Or if someone has a Bash script that can respond to the full documented set of Snapito API responses, that'd be awesome.  Here's [their API documentation](http://snapito.com/paid-api.jsp).

Thanks!

Comment: You could parse the output, but I guess this is easier in python/ruby/php/...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the dump headers option:
`curl -D /tmp/headers.txt http://server.com`

Comment: Ah, yes.  I had overlooked the `-D` option.  Here's what I'm using now: `curl -s -L -D /dev/stdout -o $IMAGE_FILE $SNAPITO_URL`  Thanks!

Comment: `curl -s -L -D - -o $IMAGE_FILE $SNAPITO_URL`

Answer (score 11):

Use `curl -i` (include HTTP header) - which will yield the headers, followed by a blank line, followed by the content.

You can then split out the headers / content (or use -D to save directly to file, as suggested above).

---

There are three options `-i`, `-I`, and `-D`

```
> curl --help | egrep '^ +\-[iID]'
 -D, --dump-header FILE  Write the headers to FILE
 -I, --head          Show document info only
 -i, --include       Include protocol headers in the output (H/F)
```

Comment: I think you were thinking of the `-I` option, not `-i`.

Comment: Nope. -I is headers only, -i is headers + content.

Comment: I see, you're right.  Using `-i` would have given me another problem though: Parsing the output to separate out the headers from the binary image data.  I got it working nicely with the `-D` option routed to stdout (and captured by a `$()` wrapper), and the `-o` option for saving the file.  Thanks though!  I'll remember to look into `-i` next time.